# A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Error: A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.
I am getting the error from below MS SQL Stored Procedure subquery.What is this mean? and How can solve this?

```
declare @pool_ids varchar(20);
    select @pool_ids = Pool_ID from wcpacker.Fruit_Pools 
                                   where Pool_ID-@Pool_ID >= -2
                                     AND Pool_ID-@Pool_ID <>  0
                                     AND Pool_ID < @Pool_ID  
     union  select top 3 Pool_ID from wcpacker.Fruit_Pools
                                   where Pool_ID >= @Pool_ID)
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with this query? What is the desired results or assignment?

Comment: Well you need to decide what you want to do - do you want to assign a variable or do you want to return 3 rows?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to reorganize the select a bit... do:

```
set @pool_ids = (select Pool_ID from .... )
```

That SHOULD work.

Comment: Except it would be assigning the value of an arbitrary Pool_ID out of the 4 that will be returned.

Comment: True. What is he trying to get for a result? a single value or an array?

Comment: that is a question I can't answer.